# Is it possible to run a function to check if a certain value in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made a calculator with jQuery and I want to add extra features to it, for example, if the display has the number 69 or 420 to initiate another function or animation to run. 
    I tried using vanilla js to grab the display, at least, but the only thing I managed to do is simply output it to the console, like this:

```
function wee(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var rezultat = document.getElementById('afis');
  console.log(rezultat.value);
}
```

Is there any way in which i can do this?

Here is the code that I have in HTML, CSS and jQuery,

```js
$(".calc-btn").on('click', function() { //selectexi elementul cu calc button ca si clasa
  if ($(this).attr('data-role') != 'operator') { //daca elementul selectat nu are rlul de operator, atunci =>>
    $(".display").val($(".display").val() + $(this).val()); //atunci displayul afiseaza valoarea displayului concatenat cu valoarea butonului 
    //toata chestia asta selecteaza un buton, verifica daca nu e un operator, iar daca nu e, concateneaza valoarea afisata pe display cu valoarea butonului apasat
  } else {
    if ($(".display").val() != '') { //verifica daca displayul e sau nu gol/ daca are sau nu o valoare
      //daca displayul nu e gol, atunci
      $(".display").val($(".display").val() + $(this).val()); // face aceeasi chestie ca sus, adica displayul afiseaza valoarea displayului concatenat cu valoarea butonului
    }
  }
});

$(".clear-btn").on('click', function() {
  $(".display").val(''); //clears the display if the clear-btn is clicked(ii da valoareao/goala/il goleste)
});

$(".calculate-btn").on('click', function() { //daca butonul calculate e pasat, atunci
  var expression = $(".display").val();
  $(".display").val(eval(expression));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tr>
          <td colspan="1">
            <input class="display" type="text" name="Display">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <table class="table">
              <tr>
                <td><input class="calc-btn" data-role="number" type="button" value="7"></td>
                <td><input class="calc-btn" data-role="number" type="button" value="8"></td>
                <td><input class="calc-btn" data-role="number" type="button" value="9"></td>
                <td><input class="calc-btn" data-role="operator" type="button" value="+"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><input class="calc-btn" data-role="number" type="button" value="4"></td>
                <td><input class="calc-btn" data-role="number" type="button" value="5"></td>
                <td><input class="calc-btn" data-role="number" type="button" value="6"></td>
                <td><input class="calc-btn" data-role="operator" type="button" value="-"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><input class="calc-btn" data-role="number" type="button" value="1"></td>
                <td><input class="calc-btn" data-role="number" type="button" value="2"></td>
                <td><input class="calc-btn" data-role="number" type="button" value="3"></td>
                <td><input class="calc-btn" data-role="operator" type="button" value="*"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><input class="clear-btn" type="button" value="C"></td>
                <td><input class="calc-btn" data-role="number" type="button" value="0"></td>
                <td><input class="calculate-btn" type="button" value="="></td>
                <td><input class="calc-btn" data-role="operator" type="button" value="/"></td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. If you want to check the input value, use `includes` i:e `const val = +$(".display").val();. if([69 , 420].includes(val)) { // code }.`

Comment: i want to check both the input value and the output. so if the either the result or one of the number being inputed.